# Having some trouble converting a tk PhotoImage back to a PIL image to save

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I'm working on a program that will convert an image to grayscale, or invert the colors. It's using different algorithms for grayscale and most everything is working fine but I have a couple of problems that I've been trying to overcome. One issue I have is trying to save the image out. So that I could handle different file types I used PIL to open the image, then convert it to a tk `PhotoImage`. Now that the image is a `PhotoImage` I can't figure out a way to save, and Tkinter's documentation mentions a way but this fails. Another problem I have is that I want to use a checkbox to rotate the image, I have a function `rotateIt` that does this, but I wasn't able to get the checkbox working because of the `IntVar()` doesn't seem to change, note my use of lambda to make it work with the radio buttons. (Thanks to another member here) Here is the code for the program. (I'm still learning, having trouble figuring out how not to use the global variables to accomplish the same tasks.)

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from graphics import GraphWin
from tkinter import filedialog # Will be used to open the file from the user
import tkinter
import os

# Global variables for radio buttons----
radio1 = True
radio2 = False
radio3 = False
radio4 = False
#--------------------------------------------

# Global variables for picture-----------
pic = ''
tkPic = ''
tkPic2 = ''
picToConvert = ''
picWidth = 0
picHeight = 0
canvas1 = ''
#---------------------------------------------

def rotateIt(pic1):
    pictureRotated = pic1.rotate(180)
    return pictureRotated
# Function for radio buttons

def whichSelected(numberSelected):
        global radio1
        global radio2
        global radio3
        global radio4
        if numberSelected == 4:
            radio1 = False
            radio4 = True
        if numberSelected == 3:
            radio1 = False
            radio3 = True
        if numberSelected == 2:
            radio1 = False
            radio2 = True
        if numberSelected == 1:
            radio1 = True


# Gray Algorithms---------------------------------------------
def grayAverage(r,g,b):
    algorithm = (r + g + b) // 3
    return (algorithm)

def invertRGB(r,g,b):
        r = 255 - r
        g = 255 - g
        b = 255 - b
        return (r,g,b)

def lightness(r,g,b):
        algorithm = (max(r, g, b) + min(r, g, b)) // 2
        return (algorithm)

def luminosity(r,g,b):
        algorithm = int(((0.21 * r) + (0.71 * g) + (0.07 * b)))
        return (algorithm)

def getRGB(r,g,b):
        red = eval( input ("Enter the value of red: "))
        green = eval(input ("Enter the value of green: "))
        blue = eval(input ("Enter the value of blue: "))
        algorithm =  red-r + green-g + blue-b // 3
        return (algorithm)
# End Gray Algorithms-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Draws window, opens picture selected by user, packs the canvas
def drawWindow():
    window = tkinter.Tk()
    window.title(os.environ.get( "USERNAME" )) # sets the window title to the
    return window

def drawCanvas():
    global window
    global canvas1
    canvas1 = tkinter.Canvas(window, width = 820, height =340) # Draws a canvas onto the tkinter window
    canvas1.pack()
    return canvas1

# Global variables for window and canvas
window = drawWindow()
canvas1 = drawCanvas()
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    # Radio Button Code---------------------------------------------------------
def drawRadioButtons():
    global window
    var = tkinter.IntVar()
    option1 = tkinter.Radiobutton(window, text ='Average Grayscale           ',variable = var, value = 1,command =  lambda: whichSelected(1))
    option2 = tkinter.Radiobutton(window, text ='Lightness Grayscale         ',variable = var, value = 2, command = lambda: whichSelected(2))
    option3 = tkinter.Radiobutton(window, text ='Luminosity Grayscale      ',variable = var, value = 3, command = lambda: whichSelected(3))
    option4 = tkinter.Radiobutton(window, text ='Invert',variable = var, value = 4, command = lambda: whichSelected(4))

    option1.select() # Sets the first button to clicked
    # Pack Radio Buttons
    option1.pack(anchor = 'sw')
    option2.pack(anchor = 'sw')
    option3.pack(anchor = 'sw')
    option4.pack(anchor = 'sw')
    # End Radio Button code ---------------------------------------------------------

def openImage():
    global window
    global canvas1
    global pic
    global picWidth
    global picHeight
    global tkPic
    global tkPic2
    global picToConvert
    canvas1.delete('all')
    del pic
    del tkPic
    picToConvert = filedialog.askopenfilename(defaultextension='.jpg') # Used to open the file selected by the user
    pic = Image.open(picToConvert)
    picWidth, picHeight = pic.size # PIL method .size gives both the width and height of a picture
    tkPic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pic, master = window) # Converts the pic image to a tk PhotoImage
    canvas1.create_image(10,10,anchor='nw', image = tkPic)

def saveImage():
    global pic
    global tkPic2
    pic = Image.open(tkPic2)
    toSave = filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w',defaultextension='.jpg')
    pic.save(toSave)

def change_pixel():
    global window
    global canvas1
    global tkPic2
    global pic
    global radio1
    global radio2
    global radio3
    global radio4
    # Treats the image as a 2d array, iterates through changing the
    #values of each pixel with the algorithm for gray

    rgbList = pic.load() #Get a 2d array of the pixels
    for row in range(picWidth):
        for column in range(picHeight):
            rgb = rgbList[row,column]
            r,g,b = rgb # Unpacks the RGB value tuple per pixel
            if radio1 == True:
                grayAlgorithm1 = grayAverage(r,g,b)
                rgbList[row,column] = (grayAlgorithm1, grayAlgorithm1, grayAlgorithm1)
            elif radio2 == True:
                grayAlgorithm1 = lightness(r,g,b)
                rgbList[row,column] = (grayAlgorithm1, grayAlgorithm1, grayAlgorithm1)
            elif radio3 == True:
                grayAlgorithm1= luminosity(r,g,b)
                rgbList[row,column] = (grayAlgorithm1, grayAlgorithm1, grayAlgorithm1) # Gives each pixel a new RGB value
            elif radio4 == True:
                r,g,b= invertRGB(r,g,b)
                rgbList[row,column] = (r, g, b) # Gives each pixel a new RGB value
        # Converting to a tkinter PhotoImage
    del tkPic2
    tkPic2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pic, master = window)
    canvas1.create_image(815,170, anchor='e',image = tkPic2)

# Function to create a button, takes the button text and the function to be called on click
def tkButtonCreate(text, command):
    tkinter.Button(window, text = text, command = command).pack()

def main():
    drawRadioButtons()
    tkButtonCreate('Open Image',openImage)
    tkButtonCreate('Convert', change_pixel)
    tkButtonCreate('Save',saveImage)
    window.mainloop()
    #convertButton = tkinter.Button(window,text = 'Convert', command = change_pixel).pack()
main()
```

Comment: "... but this fails. " define "fails". Do you get an error? Is the image saved in the original state? Is the image not saved but tkinter reports that it is?

Comment: Tk's documentation shows a .save() method that works using an IO string object. This fails I assume because it can't write PILs PhotoImage

Comment: _how_ does it fail? Does it crash? Throw an error? What error?

Comment: This is the error I receive. It looks like .save() isn't valid for a PhotoImage.`Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1475, in __call__ return self.func(*args) File "L:\Final Project\#Greyscale_rev8.py", line 138, in saveImage tkPic2.save(toSave) AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute 'save'`

Comment: Way too late, but regarding the question in the title, there is a getimage( imagetk ) function in the ImageTk interface. See my answer to a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67004502/734848

Comment: Tried to edit my previous post, but there is a 5 mins window for doing so (didn't know about that). Anyway, to use getimage() in your presented saveImage() function you can just replace: pic = Image.open(tkPic2) with: pic = ImageTk.getimage(tkPic2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `pic = Image.open(tkPic2)` in `saveImage()`

To save file use:

```
def saveImage():
    global pic
    toSave = filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w',defaultextension='.jpg')
    pic.save(toSave)
```

---

**BTW:** for object better use `None` in place of `''`

```
pic = None
tkPic = None
tkPic2 = None
picToConvert = None
canvas1 = None
```

Besides, `del` gives you `None`

```
 del tkPic2 # now tkPic2 == None
```

---

**EDIT:** solution for problem with IntVar and rotation.

I create global variable `var = None` and then  I can use it in functions (using  `global var`)

I use `pic = pic.rotate(180)` to rotate "in place" without new variable.

I add radio button for `Rotation` and function `onConvert` to run `rotateIt` or `change_pixel` and now I create `tkPic2` in `onConvert`

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
#from graphics import GraphWin # not needed

# for Python 3.x
from tkinter import filedialog # Will be used to open the file from the user
import tkinter

# for Python 2.x
#import Tkinter as tkinter
#import tkFileDialog as filedialog # Will be used to open the file from the user

import os

# --- Global variables for radio buttons ---

radio1 = True
radio2 = False
radio3 = False
radio4 = False

#--------------------------------------------

# --- Global variables for picture ---

pic = None
tkPic = None
tkPic2 = None
picToConvert = None
picWidth = 0
picHeight = 0
canvas1 = None

var = None #create global variable

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

def rotateIt():
    global pic

    print "(debug) rotateIt:", pic
    pic = pic.rotate(180)

# --- Function for radio buttons ---

def whichSelected(numberSelected):
        global radio1
        global radio2
        global radio3
        global radio4

        if numberSelected == 4:
            radio1 = False
            radio4 = True
        elif numberSelected == 3:
            radio1 = False
            radio3 = True
        elif numberSelected == 2:
            radio1 = False
            radio2 = True
        elif numberSelected == 1:
            radio1 = True


# --- Gray Algorithms ---

def grayAverage(r, g, b):
    return (r + g + b) // 3

def invertRGB(r,g,b):
    return (255 - r, 255 - g, 255 - b)


def lightness(r,g,b):
    return (max(r, g, b) + min(r, g, b)) // 2

def luminosity(r,g,b):
    return int(((0.21 * r) + (0.71 * g) + (0.07 * b)))

def getRGB(r,g,b):
    red   = eval(input("Enter the value of red: "))
    green = eval(input("Enter the value of green: "))
    blue  = eval(input("Enter the value of blue: "))

    return red-r + green-g + blue-b // 3

# --- End Gray Algorithms ---

# Draws window, opens picture selected by user, packs the canvas
def drawWindow():
    window = tkinter.Tk()
    window.title(os.environ.get( "USERNAME" )) # sets the window title to the

    return window

def drawCanvas():
    global window
    global canvas1
    canvas1 = tkinter.Canvas(window, width = 820, height =340) # Draws a canvas onto the tkinter window
    canvas1.pack()

    return canvas1

# Global variables for window and canvas
window = drawWindow()
canvas1 = drawCanvas()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

# --- Radio Button Code ---

def drawRadioButtons():
    global window, var

    var = tkinter.IntVar()

    option1 = tkinter.Radiobutton(window, text ='Average Grayscale',    variable = var, value = 1, command = lambda: whichSelected(1))
    option2 = tkinter.Radiobutton(window, text ='Lightness Grayscale',  variable = var, value = 2, command = lambda: whichSelected(2))
    option3 = tkinter.Radiobutton(window, text ='Luminosity Grayscale', variable = var, value = 3, command = lambda: whichSelected(3))
    option4 = tkinter.Radiobutton(window, text ='Invert',               variable = var, value = 4, command = lambda: whichSelected(4))
    option5 = tkinter.Radiobutton(window, text ='Rotate 180',           variable = var, value = 5)

    # Sets the first button to clicked
    option1.select()

    # Pack Radio Buttons
    option1.pack(anchor = 'sw')
    option2.pack(anchor = 'sw')
    option3.pack(anchor = 'sw')
    option4.pack(anchor = 'sw')
    option5.pack(anchor = 'sw')
    # End Radio Button code 

def openImage():
    global window
    global canvas1
    global pic
    global picWidth
    global picHeight
    global tkPic
    global tkPic2
    global picToConvert

    canvas1.delete('all')
    del pic
    del tkPic

    picToConvert = filedialog.askopenfilename(defaultextension='.jpg') # Used to open the file selected by the user
    pic = Image.open(picToConvert).convert('RGB')
    picWidth, picHeight = pic.size # PIL method .size gives both the width and height of a picture
    tkPic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pic, master = window) # Converts the pic image to a tk PhotoImage
    canvas1.create_image(10,10,anchor='nw', image = tkPic)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

def saveImage():
    global pic

    toSave = filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w',defaultextension='.jpg')
    pic.save(toSave)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

def onConvert():
    global var
    global tkPic2
    global window

    if var.get() == 5:
        rotateIt(pic)
    else:
        change_pixel()

    # Converting to a tkinter PhotoImage

    if tkPic2:
        del tkPic2

    tkPic2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pic, master = window)
    canvas1.create_image(815,170, anchor='e',image = tkPic2)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

def change_pixel():
    global window
    global canvas1
    global pic

    global radio1
    global radio2
    global radio3
    global radio4

    # Treats the image as a 2d array, iterates through changing the
    #values of each pixel with the algorithm for gray

    rgbList = pic.load() #Get a 2d array of the pixels
    for row in range(picWidth):
        for column in range(picHeight):
            rgb = rgbList[row,column]
            #print rgb
            r,g,b = rgb # Unpacks the RGB value tuple per pixel
            if radio1 == True:
                grayAlgorithm1 = grayAverage(r,g,b)
                rgbList[row,column] = (grayAlgorithm1, grayAlgorithm1, grayAlgorithm1)
            elif radio2 == True:
                grayAlgorithm1 = lightness(r,g,b)
                rgbList[row,column] = (grayAlgorithm1, grayAlgorithm1, grayAlgorithm1)
            elif radio3 == True:
                grayAlgorithm1= luminosity(r,g,b)
                rgbList[row,column] = (grayAlgorithm1, grayAlgorithm1, grayAlgorithm1) # Gives each pixel a new RGB value
            elif radio4 == True:
                rgbList[row,column] = invertRGB(r,g,b) # Gives each pixel a new RGB value

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Function to create a button, takes the button text and the function to be called on click
def tkButtonCreate(text, command):
    tkinter.Button(window, text = text, command = command).pack()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

def main():
    drawRadioButtons()
    tkButtonCreate('Open Image',openImage)
    tkButtonCreate('Convert', onConvert)
    tkButtonCreate('Save',saveImage)
    window.mainloop()
    #convertButton = tkinter.Button(window,text = 'Convert', command = change_pixel).pack()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

main()
```

Comment: This is the output after making those changes to `saveImage()` I think this is the original error I received the first time I started trying to get this to save. `Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1475, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "L:\Final Project\#Greyscale_rev8.py", line 138, in saveImage
    tkPic2.save(toSave)
AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute 'save'`

Comment: I switched those to None, using None makes more sense, thanks for this.

Comment: I correct code - I see you have converted image in `pic` so there is no need to use `tkPic2`

Comment: BTW: I had problem with my images because they were not 24bit so I had to use `convert("RGB")` in `pic = Image.open(picToConvert).convert("RGB")`

Comment: This works. I now understand whats going on with the picture objects so much better. I now see that when I'm opening the pic object that though I set it to tkPic2 the data is still edited in pic. I can now figure out how to better clear the canvas after each conversion, thanks!

Comment: Any idea on how to get a checkbox working with my `rotateIt()` function? I built a checkbox but it didn't seem like IntVar() ever changed. I tried to set `var = tkinter.IntVar()` and `onvalue = 1` and `offvalue = 0` and check against those values with `if var.get() == 1: rotateIt()` but using print statement var never changed. I'm still trying to understand how I can pass data between functions without using globals. I know that if all of the functions are in a class that they can use one another's variables much easier, but I'm not quite there yet.

Comment: I suppose you need to use `global var` but I have to look at code.

Comment: I add new code with `global var` and working rotation. There are other problems - for example: what if try to do rotation but you didn't load image ? ;)