# How to convert ImageTk to Image?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

Let's say I have some `ImageTk.PhotoImage` image stored in the variable `imgtk`. How can I convert it back to an `Image.Image`?

The reason is that I want to resize it, but it seems that `.resize()` only works for `Image.Image`s.

Comment: I think I have the solution, bear with me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, that was not easy but I think I have a solution though you need to go into some private methods of `label.image`. Maybe there is a better way if so I would love to see.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Label
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = tk.Tk()

# create label1 with an image
image = Image.open('pic1.jpg')
image = image.resize((500, 750), Image.ANTIALIAS)
picture = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=image)
label1 = Label(root, image=picture)
label1.image = picture

# extract rgb from image of label1
width, height = label1.image._PhotoImage__size
rgb = np.empty((height, width, 3))
for j in range(height):
    for i in range(width):
        rgb[j, i, :] = label1.image._PhotoImage__photo.get(x=i, y=j)

# create new image from rgb, resize and use for label2
new_image = Image.fromarray(rgb.astype('uint8'))
new_image = new_image.resize((250, 300), Image.ANTIALIAS)
picture2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=new_image)
label2 = Label(root, image=picture2)
label2.image = picture2

# grid the two labels
label1.grid(row=0, column=0)
label2.grid(row=0, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Actually you can zoom and reduce the original picture by using the methods `zoom` to enlarge the picture (`zoom(2)` doubles the size) and `subsample` to reduce the size (`subsample(2)` halves the picture size).

for example

```
picture2 = label1.image._PhotoImage__photo.subsample(4)
```

reduces the size of the picture to a quarter and you can skip all the conversion to an Image.

According to `label1.image._PhotoImage__photo.subsample.__doc__`:

> Return a new PhotoImage based on the same image as this widget but use only every Xth or Yth pixel.  If y is not given, the default value is the same as x

and `label1.image._PhotoImage__photo.zoom.__doc__`:

> Return a new PhotoImage with the same image as this widget but zoom it with a factor of x in the X direction and y in the Y direction.  If y is not given, the default value is the same as x.

Comment: It is kinda unfortunate that there doesn't seem to be any built-in to do that.

Comment: Yes you would think there should be a more straightforward way to extract the image from a widget! :)

Comment: Actually the `_PhotoImage__photo` has two interesting methods `zoom` and `subsample` to increase or reduce the size of the picture. I have added this to the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the help! I also just came across these two methods - including their issues: Both methods only seem to be able to handle integer factors, which means you *could* use them both for fractional factors, but depending on the factors this might consume a lot of memory.

Comment: But probably quicker than going via the Image route, that seems to take quite a bit of time to fill the array

Comment: I agree:) For my particular application I'm probably now gonna switch to the "lazy" way of implementing everything for `Image.Image`s and converting them to `ImageTk.PhotoImage`s when needed.

Comment: I wonder though why _PhotoImage__Photo is not made public? Anyway good luck, it was interesting to sort this out...

Answer (score 7):

I know it is awfully late, but I just came across the same issue and I just discovered that there is a **getimage(imagetk)** function in the [ImageTk interface](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/PIL/ImageTk.html).

So, to get your imgtk back as an PIL Image you can do:

```
img = ImageTk.getimage( imgtk )
```

I just did a quick test on Windows (Python 3.8.5/Pillow 8.1.2/Tkinter 8.6) and it seems to work fine:

```
# imgtk is an ImageTk.PhotoImage object
img = ImageTk.getimage( imgtk )
img.show()
img.close()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I don't think I would ever have found this methods - I will have to try this, as it could have saved me quite a bit of work:)

Comment: You are welcome! The show() and close() methods are documented in the Image module, but the ImageTk.getimage() interface function was really hard to find. Actually I only found it by looking at the source code.