# TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'm'

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter

I use the following code to open and save an image via OpenCV in Tkinter:

```
def select_image():
    fln = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=os.getcwd(), title="Select image file", filetypes=(("JPG File","*.jpg"), ("PNG file", "*.png"), ("All Files", "*.*")))
    img = Image.open(fln)
    img.thumbnail((350,350))
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    lbl.configure(image=img)
    lbl.image = img
    img = np.array(img)

    cv2.imwrite(cv2.UMat("C:/Users/User/Desktop/Kurkuma/SEG" + ".jpg", img))
```

When I run this code I get the following error:
TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'm'

I am not that familiar with OpenCV and Tkinter, so I have no clue how to fix this. Can anyone tell me what's wrong or what I have to change?

Comment: Instead of `cv2.imwrite(cv2.UMat("C:/Users/User/Desktop/Kurkuma/SEG" + ".jpg", img))`, try: `cv2.imwrite("C:/Users/User/Desktop/Kurkuma/SEG/img.jpg", img)`

Comment: Than I get this error: TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'img'

Comment: @ThijsBrokking Are you sure you can call `np.asarray(...)` on a `ImageTk.PhotoImage` object? I don't know much about `cv2` but I don't think you should be doing that.

Comment: @TheLizzard I am not sure at all, I guess that's the problem. But if you have any solutions the fix this, I am open to everything.

Comment: @ThijsBrokking You don't need to use OpenCV for saving the image. Check my updated answer.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `ImageTk.getimage(img)` before converting to NumPy array.
You also need to convert the color format from RGBA to BGR before saving as JPEG.

Code sample:

```
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)  # Type of img is PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58389742/how-to-convert-imagetk-to-image
img = np.array(ImageTk.getimage(img))  # Get the image, and then convert it to NumPy array

img_bgr = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2BGR)  # Convent from RGBA to BGR color space

cv2.imwrite("img.jpg", img_bgr)  # Save to JPEG.
```

---

A more efficient solution is not using OpenCV, and not using `ImageTk.PhotoImage`.

You can simply use pillow for saving the image using `img.save`:

```
img.thumbnail((350,350))
img.save("img.jpg")
```

Comment: This isn't efficient. The thing that you get out of `ImageTk.getimage(img)` is the same as the thing that you get from `Image.open(fln)` which OP already does

Comment: @TheLizzard Sure... But in the general case, if what you have is the result of `ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)`, you need to use `ImageTk.getimage`

Answer (score 1):

You should not use the result of `ImageTk.PhotoImage` in `np.array(img)`.  Use result from `Image`:

```py
def select_image():
    fln = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=os.getcwd(), title="Select image file", filetypes=(("JPG File","*.jpg"), ("PNG file", "*.png"), ("All Files", "*.*")))
    if fln:
        img = Image.open(fln)
        img.thumbnail((350,350))

        tkimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img) # use another variable
        lbl.configure(image=tkimg)
        lbl.image = tkimg

        img = np.array(img) # use result from Image.open()
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR) # convert RGB to BGR

        cv2.imwrite("C:/Users/User/Desktop/Kurkuma/SEG.jpg", img)
```

Comment: @ThijsBrokking If this answer solved your problem, try accepting it. Click [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to learn how to do that.